# Insert within a trigger not executing correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an insert, update trigger where I'm just trying to insert the variable value to a table.  It's one `field/variable` that is `nchar(100)`:

```
DECLARE @Name nchar(100)

SET @Name = LEFT((select top 1 ISNULL(Name, '') 
                  from   inserted 
                  inner join dbo.accounts on inserted.id = dbo.accounts.id_c), 25) 

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO CRM.dbo.TestName (name) VALUES (@Name)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH;
```

Looking at the trace, I see each line of the `TRY` being executed (`SP:StmtStarting` and `SP:StmtCompleted`), but when I check the table itself nothing is inserted.

How can I determine why this is happening?

Comment: Also, I've tried just 'test' instead of @Name and got nothing.  Another weird part is I initially had success with a SELECT INTO statement.  I executed it, deleted the table, and literally executed the trigger with the exact same statement in it to no success.

Comment: I've also confirmed that executing the insert statement as the user that executes this trigger outside of the trigger does work.

Comment: what you get in @Name? and what is the datatype of name

Comment: The field in the source table is nvarchar(150).  The variable is nchar(100) (not sure why it's 100, since the first 25 characters are being used).  But, like I said, the statement doesn't even work for a hard-coded string.

Comment: Is it the only trigger on this table? if you try a simple insert statmnt without try/catch does it work?

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. Your logic assume there will only ever be a single row affected. I see that you have top 1 but what are you really trying to do here? Of course top 1 with no order by means you don't even know which row will be returned.

Comment: I agree with Sean Lange. You should check @@ROWCOUNT. If its one, go ahead and insert normally without TOP. If its more than one, you need to INSERT INTO with a SELECT from the "inserted" table

Comment: That's part of the problem Sean.  Someone else wrote this trigger, and I don't have much experience with troubleshooting them.  I'm trying to figure out what's being stored in the variables, because there is an issue.  Dudi, a simple insert statement without the try/catch doesn't work.  I was hoping to look at an error message with that catch, but the try goes through (though without the actual results in the table).

Comment: You should also use a variable that matches what you want to insert into the TestName table. If TestName.name is varchar(150) you wil want to do a CAST at least.

Comment: Since I've discovered that a simple INSERT INTO CRM.dbo.TestName (name) VALUES ('Test') command doesn't work. I think that is the first issue to tackle.  I'm pretty confused as to why something like that would execute, but not actually insert (considering I've confirmed that the statement works outside of the trigger with the same user).

Comment: You may actually be getting an error back from the `INSERT` statement but you dont' know about it. `TRY CATCH` does not work for _all_ errors. See the section "Errors Unaffected by a TRY…CATCH Construct" in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx). I very much doubt that any of these type of errors are causing your problem, but it is worth being aware of none the less.

Comment: @SeanLange - It looks like the trigger should handle multiple rows. It uses `TOP` _without `ORDER BY`_ to pick a row to process. Probably not a good idea, but not fatal.

Comment: Yes I stated as coded it will work but once you see scalar variables in a trigger it is a very good indication that it about to the wrong direction.

Comment: @user3043028, Can you insert into any other table from inside the tigger, or is this just isolated to the `CRM.dbo.TestName` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how my trigger was failing, but I'm not 100% on why.  I had another insert statement to a linked server table further down the trigger.  The raiseerror command helped me figure out what was going wrong with that insert statement, and after I fixed that error, the insert statement in my question executed successfully.

What I don't get is, even with explicitly putting the insert within a BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT TRAN, it still wouldn't execute if the next insert didn't work?  Is that just how a trigger works?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following statement in your trigger. Keep the `TRY/CATCH` block because SQL Server will throw an exception if it tries to perform `INSERT INTO` with zero records.

```
BEGIN TRY
  INSERT INTO [crm].[dbo].[TestName] ([Name])
  SELECT LEFT(ISNULL([Name], ''), 25)
  FROM [inserted]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[accounts]
    ON ([dbo].[accounts].[id_c] = [inserted].[id]);
END TRY BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;
```

What trigger are you using this in, *e.g.* `AFTER INSERT`, `AFTER UPDATE`? If you're doing this in `AFTER INSERT`, can you expect something in `accounts` to match with `inserted.id`. It appears to be a primary key and probably shouldn't exist in `accounts` prior to the record being inserted.

Comment: I tried that, but got nothing.  But I think the issue is inserting in general from the trigger.  If SQL Server is throwing an error, I wouldn't be seeing it.  What would I do to see it?

Comment: Actually - I'd use raiserror within the CATCH, but the TRY statement goes through.